# Почему discord бот отправляет несколько сообщений?

Tags: discord, бот, discord.py

В начале, когда я начинал писать код, у меня было всё нормально, но когда я уже добавил где-то 10 команд. Бот начал отправлять несколько сообщений, как будто я прописал это в коде.

Я уже проверял, что может это из-за того, что я добавил много команд. Но нет, это не решило проблему.

Чуть раньше я решал эту проблему , просто перезагрузив компьютер, но сейчас такое не сработает.

Эта ошибка не выводится в консоль. Также ошибка не в пробелах.

Основной код:

settings.py

```
#Настройик бота

import discord
from discord.ext import commands

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = "-")
tokens = "*******************"

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Бот запущен!")
    bot.loop.create_task(status_task())

async def status_task():
    while True:
        await bot.change_presence(status = discord.Status.idle, activity = discord.Game("-help"))
```

Ещё основной код:

main.py

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from settings import tokens
from settings import bot

#Модерирование
import mut
import clear
import ban
import kick
import unban

#Полезные команды
import ping
import poll
import giveaway
import report
import privatgoloc

#Фан команды
import coin
import roll
import selfik

#Музыкальные команды

#Информация
import infoserver
import helps

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, commands.CommandNotFound ):
        await ctx.send(embed = discord.Embed(description = f' {ctx.author.name}, данной команды не существует.', color=0x0c0c0c))

bot.run(tokens)
```

Answer (score 0):

Если у тебя есть ивент `on_message()` в твоём коде, то скорее всего в нём прописана строчка `await bot.process_command(message)`, может быть даже не один раз. 
Попробуй убрать её, всё должно исправиться.


Если это не поможет, то проверь, чтобы бот был запущен лишь 1 раз.